# Ubuntu desktop installation problem, a lot of error messages

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, squashfs

I am getting error messages while trying to install ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop (Intel Pentium D). The error messages are:

```
*checking battery state...
[412.633532] end_request:I/O error .dev sr0, sector 1291684
[435.997503] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_readdata failed to readbloack 0x275fcda4
[435.9975xx] SQUASHFS error: unable to read fragment cache entry page [275fcda4]
...
[524.000055] exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
ata5.00 : cmd a0/00:00:00:08:00/00:00:00/00 tag0 pio 16392 in res 58 /00:02:00:08:00/00/a0 Emask 0xf(timeout)
[524.000292] ata5.00 status : {DRDY DRQ}
```

I was able to install on another PC (Intel Atom) but not on this PC (Intel Pentium D), Can any one help me in successful installation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [Squashfs Errors community help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquashfsErrors). This might help you to resolve the issue.

Here is the gist of the fix provided.

> **Temporary Workarounds**
>
> Some users have reported that adding the ide=nodma or acpi=off allowed
>   them to work around this issue (which proved to be bad memory
>   modules). You might want to give that a try
>
> Successful boot was achieved by adding "all_generic_ide" to the grub
>   boot line for the live CD.
>
> You can add those lines to the grub entry, either in the grub.conf
>   file or either entering letter 'e' on the grub menu and after editing
>   Control+x to boot:
>
> Add to the grub line:
>
> ```
> all_generic_ide pci=nommconf
> ```
>
> Add to the kernel line:
>
> ```
> ide=nodma acpi=off
> ```

Comment: Thanks for replying. After trying to install on SATA HD and ATA HD with no result, it shows the issue is with Pentium D processor and its mother board 102 series which is not supporting Ubuntu installation. Even the side by side with windows never worked, its been years now, failed to install on this PC.